# jquery ui datepicker . options in object. 'this' inside inner functions not referencing the obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

jquery ui datepicker :

I want to pass the options as an  obj like this :

```
  obj = {
     beforeShow: function(input) {
         console.log(this);   
     }
  }
```

when I call like this : `obj.beforeShow()`, 'this' is printing as the obj that I defined at the top. When, I call like this: `$("#somelement").datepicker(obj);` , 'this' is printing as the jquery object `#someelement`.

My requirement is:

I added custom dropdown to the button panel . They contain ' yesterday, last month' . 
The same code is used to add this select box to the functions for the events `beforeShow`, and `onChangeMonthYear` . These events are automatically called when first showing the `datepicker` and when month, year changes.  But, I didn't find any event which should be fired when 'date' changes (like from 20 to 22 of that month). So,  I want to call `beforeShow` event  of that object by calling `this.beforeShow()` . But, 'this' is referred to html element . Actually I made it work by following some normal methods like directly using the object variable(obj) instead of 'this'., but want to know the correct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 obj = {
     beforeShow: jQuery.proxy(function(input) {
         console.log(this);   
     }, this)
  }
```

Try the code above.

**EDIT:** Explanation

This is a scope issue. When you define one function inside other, the `this` inside the inner function will refer to the inner function. If you want `this` inside the inner function to refer to some other object and not the outer function, then you do something like this.

```
 var objectX = function(){};
 obj = {
     beforeShow: jQuery.proxy(function(input) {
         console.log(this);   
     }, objectX)
  }
```

*Referring to first Code Snippet:*
What the jQuery.proxy will do is change the `this` inside inner function to refer to outer function. There are other ways of doing the same. one such way is listed below. This will come in handy when you want the `this` inside the inner function to refer to inner function for some reason.

```
 var _self = this;
 obj = {
     beforeShow: function(input) {
         console.log(_self);
     }
  }
```